# How to define \newcommand as number from file using \input

Tags: macros, counters, input

I'm trying to pull a number from an external text file that contains nothing but that number and use it to define a command which I can then use to set a counter, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the contents of the external file `page.tex`:

```
107
```

Here is the MWE `main.tex` that uses that external file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\foo}{\input{page.tex}}

\setcounter{page}{\foo}

\begin{document}
  Some text.
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile, I get an error. If, however, I change `\newcommand{\foo}{\input{page.tex}}` to `\newcommand{\foo}{107}`, it works just fine, so I assume there's some problem with `\input{page.tex}`. Is it perhaps the line ending or something? I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 4):

It cannot work, because `\input` is not expandable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\newcommand{\foo}{}% for safety
\CatchFileDef{\foo}{page.tex}{}

\setcounter{page}{\foo}

\begin{document}

Test \thepage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In LaTeX the TeX-primitive `\input` is renamed to `\@@input` and `\input` is redefined to be a macro which does not work out in expansion-contexts like gathering and expanding tokens that belong to a TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity.

`\@@input`, however, as long as the file in question can be read, is expandable, but in TeX the end of a file is like an `\outer` token and therefore the end of a file cannot occur within macro-arguments or *⟨balanced text⟩* or the like.

But you are in luck:

You can arrange things so that no `\outer` end of file is encountered while TeX is grabbing macro-arguments/*⟨balanced text⟩*/the like:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% Let's create a file page.tex:
\begin{filecontents*}{page.tex}
107
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}{\@@input page.tex}
\makeatother

\setcounter{page}{\foo}
% More directly:
% \setcounter{page}{\csname @@input\endcsname page.tex}


\begin{document}

\message{%
  ^^J
  !^^J
  ! When \string\begin{document}\space was reached, the page-counter had the value \number\value{page}.^^J
  !^^J
}

Some text.
\end{document}
```

In the .log-file and on the console beneath other things you get the following message:

```
 !
 ! When \begin{document} was reached, the page-counter had the value 107.
 !
```

.pdf-output looks like this:

[image]

If you are interested in what is happening:

`\setcounter` is defined as

```latex
\setcounter=macro:
#1#2->\@ifundefined{c@#1}{\@nocounterr{#1}}{\global\csname c@#1\endcsname#2\relax}
```

, thus
`\setcounter{page}{\foo}` yields
`\@ifundefined{c@page}{\@nocounterr{page}}{\global\csname c@page\endcsname\foo\relax}`
, which —as the control-word-token `\c@page` underlying the `page`-counter is defined—at some stage yields
`\global\csname c@page\endcsname\foo\relax`
, which is something like:
`\global\c@page\foo\relax`.

Now TeX is doing a global assignment for the count-register `\c@page`. Hereby `\foo` gets expanded, so you have something like
`\global\c@page\@@input page.tex\relax`
, which—due to `\@@input` being expandable—in turn is not a problem, too: While gathering and expanding expandable tokens belonging to a TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity `\@@input` is expanded implying that the file-name is gathered and both the token `\@input` and tokens forming the filename vanish and the focus is turned towards the content of `page.tex`.
Hereby the digits `107` trailed by a space token are encountered. The space-token comes into being due to TeX's `\endlinechar`-mechanism. The space-token triggers ending gathering tokens for the TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity and is removed, and the assignment is performed.
Then TeX encounters the end of the file and the focus is turned back from `page.tex` to the main TeX file.
Things would also work out if `\endlinechar` had a negative value because things being `\outer` doesn't matter while gathering/expanding tokens belonging to a TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity. An `\outer` end of a file while gathering/expanding tokens of a TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity silently just triggers ending gathering.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you are using LaTeX, no plain TeX. If you use plain TeX then the task can be simply solved:

```
\newcount\page

\page=\input page.tex

The page is \the\page.
\bye
```